# All bijections of the set of the first N natural numbers, and the similarity between only two of those bijections

Tags: elementary-number-theory, functions

*Edit: I see I've been downvoted twice. Have I violated any policies, or is it because of my poor articulation?*

I don't know if a solution has already been found for this problem before, or even how to express it in concise yet precise terms. I am not very knowledgeable of mathematical terminology. I'll explain below what I'm looking for; please feel free to change the title, wording, and tags of this question.

I'm looking for two functions that will probably need to be developed together. I'm going to try coming up with something myself, but there's no sense in reinventing the wheel if this has already been done.

First function: f(n,m)

- Takes two integers (n,m) as variables
- n has the range [0, infinity)
- m has the range [0, n! - 1] OR [1, n!]
- f(n,m) is a unique bijection from the natural set [0,n]->[0,n]

Second function: g(n,m,r)

- Takes three integers (n,m,r) as variables
- n has the range [0, infinity)
- m and r have the range [0, n! - 1] OR [1, n!]
- g(n,m,r) is a real number in the range [0, 1)
- g(n,m,r) is a ratio representing the percentage of mappings in common between f(n,m) and f(n,r)

Has anything like this been done before?

Comment: So $f(n,m)$ is a _function_ rather than a _number_? So we cam ask, for example, whether $f(69,35)(28)=42$?

Comment: @HenningMakholm: Yes, exactly!

Comment: So $f(n,{-})$ is an enumeration of $S_n$ and $g(n,m,r)$ is $\frac1{n!}$ times  the number of fixpoints of the permutation $f(n.r)^{-1}\circ f(n,m)$?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen: That sounds right. To be sure, can the last part can be loosely rephrased (with loss of precision) as "the number of values for s such that f(n,r)(s) = f(n,m)(s)"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can certainly *define* an $f$ that meets your specification, such as recursively

```
f(n,m)(k) = let y = m mod n
            in if k = 0
               then y
               else let x = f(n-1,m div n)(k-1)
                    in if x < y then x
                                else x+1
```

(using Haskellish syntax because the usual mathematical symbolism doesn't have a nice way to represent nested case analysis and intermediate results).

*Computing* your $g$ will basically require tabulating $f(n,m)$ and $f(n,r)$ and looking for shared values position for position, though. I don't think there's any way you can get out of this by cleverly choosing a "better" $f$.

On the other hand, this is not quite as bad as it sounds, though, because typical $m$ and $r$ are going so be so large that even representing their value is going to take up $\Theta(n \log n)$ space *anyway* -- so filling out the tables and comparing them doesn't take that much more time than just *reading the inputs* in the first place (assuming we're just a bit clever about filling out the table at once instead of calling $f(n,m)(k)$ separately for $n$ different $k$s).

Comment: Thanks! I don't expect n to get much higher than 100,000, and I don't need every value of m and r. I may be able to just create a table of "useful" evaluations for function g given a fixed n value if I leave my computer running for a while.

Comment: @NickOveracker: For $n=100,000$, representing a typical $m$ is going to be a bignum that takes about 200 kilobytes to represent (and with 400 kilobytes you could just tabulate the permutation from the get-go instead of attempting to encode it as an integer), and unpacking all that information will take quite some time. It's beginning to sound a lot like you have an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) here -- what is it you're _actually_ trying to achieve?

Comment: Essentially, I am taking the input of a dictionary file (like the Linux "words" file) and mapping each word directly to a new unique word to create a new language of sorts. Languages of sufficient similarity will be "dialects".

This is to be used, if everything falls into place, in a sort of online community/game. People would be assigned a language, and people who are assigned different languages will only see the newly constructed language if they try to communicate with each other. Since it's a one-to-one mapping, though, it can be decoded with effort.

Comment: I wouldn't need a large number of languages, and I may drop the "dialect" idea for now. Or, maybe I can implement it in a different, more efficient way (such as starting with a base language, then just replacing words at random with words from a different language.)

Comment: It *might* be an XY problem, but I feel like I just described a symbolic representation of the actual problem.

Comment: @NickOveracker: For that purpose, attempting to represent each permutation as an _integer_ in the exact range 1 to $n!$ is definitely a detour and a bad design choice. It won't be significantly more compact than simply representing it as a table of what maps to what, and it _will_ be significantly slower and more cumbersome to use such a packed representation than a table

Comment: @NickOveracker: What you should _store_ in a database if you're concerned with space efficiency, would be a seed for a PRNG which you can then use to compute each user's language table when you need it. This is not as fast as storing the actual table, but will still be faster than unpacking a $[1,n!]$ integer. And by selecting how you _use_ a PRNG to produce a permutation you could design it such that you get languages in "dialect" clumps if you want that (which would be utterly implausible if you choose each language uniformly at random).

Comment: I suppose you're right - 100000! is a rather startlingly large number. And I'm not likely to encounter even a single pair of languages of significant similarity in the range of a single long integer.

Thanks! I'll try to find ways to select languages with high probabilities of being similar.

Comment: @NickOveracker: One approach would be: Start with the identity mapping. Given a language number `L`, first seed your PRNG with `L&7` and swap 100,000 randomly chosen pairs of words, giving one of 8 "language families". Then seed your PRNG with `L&31` and swap 12,500 randomly chosen pairs of words, giving one of 32 "base languages". Two languages in the same family then have at least half their vocabulary in common. Finally seed your PRNG with all of `L` and swap 5000 randomly chosen pairs, producing a "dialect". Two dialects of the same language then have about 80% commonality.

Comment: That's approach definitely sounds like a good start, and maybe even a good stop as well. I'll take off with that approach. Thank you so much for your helpful suggestions!